# RxJava: Can a Side Effect be Dependant on Another Side Effect

Tags: java, rx-java, reactivex

If I have multiple side effects (subscribes), how can I make one wait for another to finish before executing?

Take the following example:

```
SomeFile file;
SomeServer server;
Observable<String> incomingMessages;

incomingMessages.subscribe(file::append);
incomingMessages.subscribe(server::send);
```

Is there a general way to prevent the server.send() from being called until file.append() has completed? I realise one easy way is:

```
incomingMessages.subscribe(message -> {
    file.append(message);
    server.send(message);
});
```

But I am wondering if there is a more generic/composable solution.

Thanks

Comment: Have `doOnNext(file::append).doOnNext(server::send)` for example.

Comment: Tried that, it executed asynchronously (server.send was called before file.append had returned).

Comment: Correction, I was using doOnEach, problem solved, thanks!

Comment: with the doOnNext approach your subscribe method will be empty. I prefer yours, it seems "atomic"